# Returning subquery in neo4j based on two different where conditions

Tags: neo4j

I have this query in SQL:

```
  Select Id, CrawlerId,CrawlerName,
 (SELECT Count(*) from CrawlerResult cr where cr.CrawlerId = cs.CrawlerId  and            IsNew=1) as LastRunResult ,
 (SELECT Count(*) from CrawlerResult cr where cr.CrawlerId = cs.CrawlerId  ) as TotalResult
  FROM CrawlerScheduler cs
```

How to convert this query to neo4j cypher by combining CrawlerScheduler and CrawlerResult nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've replaced the foreign key relationships from SQL with actual relationships in Cypher, and that you're using actual booleans instead of 1 and 0? Something like:

```
(:CrawlerScheduler)-[:RESULT]->(:CrawlerResult)
```

If so then the equivalent Cypher query might look like this:

```
MATCH (cs:CrawlerScheduler)
WITH cs, SIZE((cs)-[:RESULT]->()) as TotalResult
OPTIONAL MATCH (cs)-[:RESULT]->(cr)
WHERE cr.IsNew
WITH cs, TotalResult, COUNT(cr) as LastRunResult
RETURN cs.Id, cs.CrawlerId, cs.CrawlerName, LastRunResult, TotalResult
```

EDIT

I changed the second match to an OPTIONAL MATCH, just in case the scheduler didn't have results, or didn't have new results.

Comment: This is the cypher I was searching for..Thanks a lot..Its working fine